# Parse string as if it were command line arguments

Tags: php

Is there easy way to parse a string so that the resulting array is the same as the `$argv` super global? Basically the inverse of that parse.

Comment: Actually that can be possible to achieve if  you  have shown sort of code or string along with expected output until and unless it is too difficult to achieve that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$argv` is the space-delimited result of the command that was invoked, so if I've understood your question correctly,

`explode(' ', $cmdString);` should do what you're looking for.

Example:

```
$cmdString = 'foo.php bar baz bing';

$argv = explode(' ', $cmdString);
$argc = count($argv);
```

Rememer that as-per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php), `$argv[0]` is the name of the script.

Comment: Yup, figured that out :(